# Editing comments using an iPhone

Tags: bug, iphone, safari

On my iPhone, it is not possible to click the `edit` link of a comment when the comment ends with a URL.

Instead of switching to edit mode, it opens the URL of the comment. This even happens on max zoom level when I can clearly tap on the edit link alone.

Comment: Hmm, seems to work alright for me. Can you provide an example text where this wasn't working?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html

Comment: I can't press edit on the comment above

Comment: Ah, it's not that the link is at the end but that it's rendered above the edit link, and the hit area overlaps in a way that makes it impossible (or at least impractical) to hit the link. Maybe a line height issue...

Comment: Yep. Sorry, I blame the lack of ability to express myself properly using the english language